# Missing directive or assembly reference

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, wcf

I need to check whether the user is opted for message alter or not for that I need to get the status and date of member by passing id. I am getting missing assembly reference or directive . I am getting error as SmsStatusResult does not contain definition for status.

Model:

```
public class SmsStatus
{
   public string Status { get; set; }
   public DateTime OptInDate { get; set; }
} 


public class SmsStatusResult : OperationResult
{
    public SmsStatus SmsStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Method :

```
public static SmsStatusResult GetSmsStatus(string memberNumber)
{
   // string Status = string.Empty, OptInDate = string.Empty;
    var Status = "";
    var OptInDate = "";


    var smsStatusResult = new SmsStatusResult();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(memberNumber))
    {
        using (
            var connection =
                new OracleConnection(
                    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleMemberConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (
                var command =
                    new OracleCommand(
                        "SELECT sms_status,sms_opt_in_date FROM member WHERE member_nbr = :memberNumber", connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(
                    new OracleParameter(
                        "memberNumber",
                        OracleDbType.Varchar2,
                        memberNumber,
                        ParameterDirection.Input));


                SmsStatusResult data;
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        data = new SmsStatusResult(); 
                        data.Status = reader["sms_status"].ToString(); //SmsStatusResult does not contain definition for status. missing a using directive or assembly reference
                        data.OptInDate = reader["sms_opt_in_date"].ToString(); SmsStatusResult does not contain definition for OptInDate . missing a using directive or assembly reference

                        break;
                    }
                     return data;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok, what assembly are you missing?  What line is giving you the error?  We need more info here

Comment: I am getting error as SmsStatusResult does not contain definition for status at line -  data.Status = reader["sms_status"].ToString();

Comment: What is `SmsStatusResult`?  Is this a class you created?

Comment: Yes it is a calss. public class SmsStatusResult : OperationResult
{
    public SmsStatus SmsStatus { get; set; }
}

Comment: ok so have you put a `using` statement at the top of your file that imports the namespace where that class is contained?

Comment: I have added the using statement and the name space namespace MembershipAPIWebService.Models but still it get the same error